# How can I display text content on the same page in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, text, innerhtml, document.write

I'm making a movie rating app so when you click the add button a form pops up. After the user has filled out the form I want the page to display the text values of the form, for example, if someone writes Lion King in the first field the page should display Movie Title: Lion King somewhere below the document but still on the same page. I've tried using the document.write method which tbh works fine but it's not good to use it and I want to display the values on the same page, not on a different page. I've also tried .innerHTML and it still isn't working but maybe I'm just doing something wrong with it. I'm not that advanced in JavaScript so please try to help me out.

```js
document.getElementById("add").addEventListener('click', 
function() {
 document.querySelector(".bg-modal").style.display = 'flex';
});
document.querySelector(".close").addEventListener('click', 
function(){
 document.querySelector(".bg-modal").style.display = 'none';
});
 const movie = document.getElementById("movie");
document.getElementById("rate");
document.getElementById("link");
document.getElementById("des");
document.getElementById("s").onclick = function() {
 document.querySelector(".bg-modal").style.display = 'none';
 document.write("<h1 id = 'mt'>" + "Movie Title" + " : " + movie.value + "</h1>")
 
 
}
```

```css
body {
 background-color:black;
}
#add {
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 background:url("https://i.ibb.co/HCW4rRn/icons8-add-100.png");
 border:none;
 position:absolute;
 top:250px;
 bottom:0;
 left:610px;
 right:0;
 cursor:pointer;
}

p {
 color:white;
 font-weight:bold;
 position:absolute;
 top:360px;
 left:455px;
 
}
.bg-modal{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 display:flex;
 justify-content:center;
 align-items:center;
 display:none;
 
 
}
.modal-content{
 width:500px;
 height:300px;
 background:linear-gradient(42deg, #403B4A,#E7E9BB);
 border-radius:5px;
 position:relative;
}
.close{
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 right:14px;
 font-size:32px;
 transform:rotate(45deg);
 cursor:pointer;
}
h1 {
 font-family: 'Hanalei', cursive;
}
h4 {
 font-family: 'Kanit', sans-serif;
 position:absolute;
 left:85px;
}
#des{
 width:150px;
 height:50px;
 position:absolute;
 left:150px;
 top:190px;
 border-color:black;
}
#movie {
 position:absolute;
 left:135px;
 border-color:black;
}
#rate {
 position:absolute;
 left:315px;
}
#link {
 position:absolute;
 left:140px;
 top:140px;
 border-color:black;
}
#s {
 border-color:white;
 text-weight:bold;
 position:absolute;
 left:195px;
 top:265px;
}
#result {
 color:white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Movie Rating App</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hanalei|Kanit&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<input type ="button" id = "add"></input>
<p>Welcome to the Movie Rating App, here you can add <br>
all of your favorite Movies and TV shows and give them<br>
ratings so that if you don't know what to watch you can<br>
always come back here. Click the add button to get started. :)</p>
<div class = "bg-modal">
 <div class = "modal-content">
 <div class = "close">+</div>
 <h1 align = "center">PLEASE FILL OUT THIS FORM</h1>
 <input type = "text" id = "movie" placeholder = "Movie Name ">
 <select id = "rate">
 <option>1</option>
 <option>2</option>
 <option>3</option>
 <option>4</option>
 <option>5</option>
 </select>
 <h4>Please put a link for the movie cover</h4>
 <input type = "url" id = "link" placeholder = "www.example.img.com">
 <br>
 <br>
 <input type = "text" placeholder = "Movie Description" id = "des" maxlength = "100">
 <br>
 <input type = "submit" id = "s">
 </div>
</div>


</body>
```

Comment: Look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore

Answer (score 2):

With `document.write` you are replacing the entire DOM of the page. Which is why it is now a "new" page. What you need is a more narrow selector.

```js
document.getElementById("add").addEventListener('click', 
function() {
 document.querySelector(".bg-modal").style.display = 'flex';
});
document.querySelector(".close").addEventListener('click', 
function(){
 document.querySelector(".bg-modal").style.display = 'none';
});
 const movie = document.getElementById("movie");
// WHAT IS HAPPENING HERE???? You are selecting a bunch of elements and not doing anything with it
document.getElementById("rate");
document.getElementById("link");
document.getElementById("des");
document.getElementById("s").onclick = function() {
 document.querySelector(".bg-modal").style.display = 'none';
    var newEl = document.createElement("p");
    newEl.innerHTML = "Movie Title" + " : " + movie.value;
    
    // Now append the new tag you created to selectedMovies div children
 document.getElementById('selectedMovies').appendChild(newEl);
 
}
```

```css
body {
 background-color:black;
}
#add {
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 background:url("https://i.ibb.co/HCW4rRn/icons8-add-100.png");
 border:none;
 position:absolute;
 top:250px;
 bottom:0;
 left:610px;
 right:0;
 cursor:pointer;
}

p {
 color:white;
 font-weight:bold;
 position:absolute;
 top:360px;
 left:455px;
 
}
.bg-modal{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 display:flex;
 justify-content:center;
 align-items:center;
 display:none;
 
 
}
.modal-content{
 width:500px;
 height:300px;
 background:linear-gradient(42deg, #403B4A,#E7E9BB);
 border-radius:5px;
 position:relative;
}
.close{
 position:absolute;
 top:0;
 right:14px;
 font-size:32px;
 transform:rotate(45deg);
 cursor:pointer;
}
h1 {
 font-family: 'Hanalei', cursive;
}
h4 {
 font-family: 'Kanit', sans-serif;
 position:absolute;
 left:85px;
}
#des{
 width:150px;
 height:50px;
 position:absolute;
 left:150px;
 top:190px;
 border-color:black;
}
#movie {
 position:absolute;
 left:135px;
 border-color:black;
}
#rate {
 position:absolute;
 left:315px;
}
#link {
 position:absolute;
 left:140px;
 top:140px;
 border-color:black;
}
#s {
 border-color:white;
 text-weight:bold;
 position:absolute;
 left:195px;
 top:265px;
}
#result {
 color:white;
}

#selectedMovies {
   position: relative;
   top: 150px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Movie Rating App</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hanalei|Kanit&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<input type ="button" id = "add"></input>
<p>Welcome to the Movie Rating App, here you can add <br>
all of your favorite Movies and TV shows and give them<br>
ratings so that if you don't know what to watch you can<br>
always come back here. Click the add button to get started. :)</p>
<div id="selectedMovies"></div>
<div class = "bg-modal">
 <div class = "modal-content">
 <div class = "close">+</div>
 <h1 align = "center">PLEASE FILL OUT THIS FORM</h1>
 <input type = "text" id = "movie" placeholder = "Movie Name ">
 <select id = "rate">
 <option>1</option>
 <option>2</option>
 <option>3</option>
 <option>4</option>
 <option>5</option>
 </select>
 <h4>Please put a link for the movie cover</h4>
 <input type = "url" id = "link" placeholder = "www.example.img.com">
 <br>
 <br>
 <input type = "text" placeholder = "Movie Description" id = "des" maxlength = "100">
 <br>
 <input type = "submit" id = "s">
 </div>
</div>


</body>
```